# Amazon Video on Demand API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, vb.net, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to write a C#/.NET application that can get results from Amazon's VoD service.  I found this article:

[Amazon API - Instant Video results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014934/amazon-api-instant-video-results)

It suggests that I use the Amazon Product Advertising API to get this information.  I have been looking at Amazon's getting started guide and various places around the internet and I am having no luck.  A lot of the information seems to be way out of date.  It looks like the latest API version is Aug 2011.  Maybe of the examples are way before that.

Are there any up-to-date examples of how to use this API from C# (VB.NET will be fine as well)?

Comment: I have been able to get results now.  One thing I didn't mention is that I am mainly interested in getting results of VoD items that are available free for Amazon Prime members.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking just for items listing use the Amazon Product Advertising API [BrowseNodeLookup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html) using  BrowseNodeId equal to 2676882011. Result according to [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=91368) should be

```
<BrowseNode>
<BrowseNodeId>2858778011</BrowseNodeId>
<Name>Amazon Instant Video</Name>
<NewReleases>
<NewRelease>
<ASIN>B007R0XM88</ASIN>
<Title>We Bought A Zoo</Title>
</NewRelease><NewRelease>
<ASIN>B007PKOKTK</ASIN>
<Title>Hop</Title>
</NewRelease>
```

But according to multiple sources the BrowseNodeID can change without notice so the best way would be iterate thru all nodes from time to time and find the valid one.
Here you will find output from Google Cache for [Amazon Instant Video](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a-uMssbtSCEAJ%3awww.browsenodes.com/node-2233263011.html%20&cd=4&hl=pl&ct=clnk&gl=pl)